# How can I restore a text file from subversion to my local folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am a newbie user of subversion.  In the "trunk" folder I have a folder with a red X over it. I understand from the subversion documentation that the next time a COMMIT is selected that the text file in that folder with a RED X next to it, "READ ME", will be deleted.  I have obviously not done a COMMIT.  I wanted to ask how can I download again just this file from the subversion repository?  Is there a way to do that?  I'm assuming yes but cannot find it when I right-click the file in Windows Explorer that shows all the Tortoisesvn options.

Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to right click on the file and go to tortoisesvn and then go to revert. You can also do this in the commit window where it lists the files.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  However, when I right-clicked the READ ME text file and selected REVERT from the tortoisesvn menu the file went away.  There is STILL a RED X on the dist folder where the file existed and also had a lib directory in it.  How do I get the file back?  When I right-clicked the dist folder it shows the dist folder checked with a status of deleted and a readme.txt file with a status of deleted also. Thanks.

Comment: If the file is gone go to show log in the folder where the file was) and find where you added it or editted it last and right click on that file and go to revert changes from this revision.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Ian.  When I tried your suggestion, the file was NOT restored in the dist directory when I looked in Windows explorer.  When I went back into the log messages in the PATH section of that dialog box it shows the path where the file is located and under the action column it shows "Added" but again it does not show up in Windows explorer.  In fact the dist folder still shows a red x on it. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: How about revert on the folder it was in and then check the file you want undeleted.